# Sorted data not plotted in correct datapoints

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn

This seems a sklearn question but it's not (at least not directly). I just use sklearn here to get the data points since this will be able to reproduce fully my problem. Some background

I use `sklearn` to predict some points in a small interval. First I build a synthetic domain `X` with 2d vectors (rows in a matrix).

Then I calculate some image points `y= x_1 + x_2 + noise` using those rows `x=(x_1, x_2)` and some noise to try to replicate some real data.

To do the regression (aka interpolation), as part of the method I fetch randomly pick vectors/points (here in matrix form they are rows) from the domain `X` using the command `train_test_split`, I will skip the details, but the result arrays are random subsets of the space (the space is `(x_1, x_2, y)` for all `(x_1, x_2)` in my compact support.

Then I do the **regression** using sklearn, so far so good. everything works as expected. And I get in `y_pred_test_sine` the predictions and they work well. But the prediction is completely shuffled since the method picks random points from domain as a *test set*.

Here comes the problem...

Since I want to plot as a continous function (being interpolated by matplotlib, and that is ok, I will play with my own interpolations tests later). I do two things:

1. Create a new vector with sorted predicted image points from test `X_test_sort`
2. Create a new vector with sorted domain points from test. `y_pred_test_sine_sort`

These (1) and (2) match (at least should) each data point in the predicted model (these are only sorted to be easily plotted using `plt.plot` lines, and not markers)

Then I plot them and they do not match (AT ALL) the expected points in my solution space.

[image]

Here we can see that the full black line (the sorted predicted line) do not follow the orange dots (the predicted points). And that was not what I expect at all.

Here follow the code to reproduce the issue.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

plt.close('all')

rng = np.random.RandomState(42)
regressor = LinearRegression()

# Synthetic dataset
x_1 = np.linspace(-3, 3, 300)
x_2 = np.sin(4*x_1)
noise = rng.uniform(size=len(x_1))
y = x_1 + x_2 + noise
X = np.vstack((x_1, x_2)).T

# Data splitting
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)

# Regression 2 features data
fit_sine = regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred_test_sine = regressor.predict(X_test)

# Here I have sorted the X values and its image points Y = f(x)
# Why those are not correctly placed over the 'prediction' points
X_test_sort = np.sort(X_test[:,0].ravel())
y_pred_test_sine_sort = np.sort(y_pred_test_sine.ravel())

# DO THE PLOTTING
plt.plot(X_test[:,0], y_test, 'o', alpha=.5, label='data')
plt.plot(X_test[:,0], y_pred_test_sine, 'o', alpha=.5, label='prediction')
plt.plot(X_test_sort, y_pred_test_sine_sort, 'k', label='prediction line')
plt.plot(x, np.sin(4*x)+x+.5, 'k:', alpha=0.3, label='trend')
plt.legend()
```

Comment: wow. I saw a conceptual problem after explain, sorting the image space will mess up completely with the oscillating information from senoidal data. Hence probably the problem. So I will need somehow sort both `X_test[:,0]` and `y_pred_test_sine` at same time using the first as guidance. I think that will fix. Any ideas in how to do it.?

Comment: I think `np.argsort()` will help me somehow.

Comment: Hi @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, this is not the same as the question you marked as duplicated, the one marked as duplicate is about plot drawn in order is plotted (that isn't the issue here, I knew that already), the problem here is about wrong sorting assumptions, hence giving the wrong data points. While both are related (since are both based in matplotlib), they are not the same. But yes. Now that I found the issue, I think that the title should changed to something more meaningful.

Comment: The duplicate shows you exactly the solution to your problem, which is to sort the y values according to the sorted x values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in your comments, by sorting `y`, you ruin the connection between `X` and `y` by place. Instead, use use argsort to get the sorting order of `X`, and then order X_test and y with that:

```
argsort_X_test = np.argsort((X_test[:,0].ravel()))
X_test_sort = X_test[argsort_X_test, 0]
y_pred_test_sine_sort = y_pred_test_sine[argsort_X_test]
```

This will give you the desired graph

[image]

Comment: yes. Did here already.